# Update media file url in wordpress media library

Tags: urls, media, media-library

Currently my videos are hosted within my wp installation. I want to move all videos to my new server.

Currently, my media url are as follows
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/video01.mp4

I am moving all videos to my central media server which will have this new url
http://media.mysite.com/videos/video01.mp4

My site will continue to be hosted where it is right now. I will only move media files.

I was hoping Velvet Blues Update URLs will be up for the job but it does not find any url to update on my website.

Probably because I am using JW player on my site and JW player post video using shortcode and ID only on the post area.

```
[jwplayer mediaid="13441"]
```

No URL on the post. Maybe this is the reason why velvet blue is not picking up the URLS to update.

Having said that, is there a way to update all media urls in wordpress install from the media library as if it was added as external url?

Which database entries holds the media URL? I am guessing my last resort will be to run find and replace on my database.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way to update all media urls in wordpress

I had a similar issue with my media files not having the correct file location after a Wordpress upgrade (somehow all the media links switched to a crazy incorrect directory), so I found [Upload URL and Path Enabler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-url-path-enabler/) which was able to rewrite all media URLs to a different path location where all my media was actually being stored.

Hope that helps someone else too!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create custom function to replace your old wp_attachment_url.

Assume you have same file name on your new media url, so you can add filter for jw player plugins only, something like this:

```
 if ( has_shortcode( get_the_content(), 'jw_player' ) ) { 
     function mynewmediaurl($wp_get_attachment_url){
$newmediadir = 'http://yourdomain/video/';
    $filename = basename($wp_get_attachment_url );
    $newurl = $newmediadir.$filename;
        return $newurl;
        }
    add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'mynewmediaurl');
    }
```

you can add in your functions.php

**Reference:**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/

Answer (score 1):

Use WP-CLI's [`search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) command to locate database entries with the old URL and replace them with the new one.  You also can do a `--dry-run` to see how many entries are affected.

```
$ wp search-replace 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/' 'http://media.example.com/videos/' --dry-run
```

Comment: I have wasted many, many hours trying these "simple" wp cli "solutions". I have never once gotten the `wp` command to do anything besides spit up errors that I didn't understand and that I couldn't find explained anywhere online. There needs to be a working solution to this.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that there are limited video in your site. you can replace URL by do following :

Expert your site database , Replace URL and import again. This is safe way to replace URL. You can do same thing using sql query also but that can cause problem sometime.

Comment: unfortunately there are around 1000 videos. editing manually is not something I am considering at this point unless there is no possibility of doing it using some kind of find and replace method

Comment: Right but find and replace can harm other URL..

Comment: from my stand point and the nature of my website, I can live images not showing up than videos not playing. As long as videos load properly, I can manually hunt the other urls such as images to correct it manually over time. thanks

Comment: With some command line trickery, you can generate a list of all mp4 files in your wp-content/uploads folder, filter out the folder path in a text editor using search and replace, then pass the results line by line into WP CLI's search replace command. You don't need to do each one by hand 1 by 1